# From in your mouth into mine?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

In the musicnotes preview of "Between two lungs" by Florence and the Machine (https://www.musicnotes.com/sheetmusic/mtd.asp?ppn=MN0078870 ;p. 5) it looks like there comes an "in" after "from" which would result in "it slipped from *in* your mouth into mine".

Is that a valid usage of a prepositional phrase with a prepositional complement?
I'm non-native so i'm not sure if that's actually a gramatically correct sentence in English. If there is no "in" she must be adding some kind of vowel after "from" because it sounds so in the song (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r3yxfU4Gpw ;2:05,2:17).

Would that be a epenthesis/paragoge then? Could someone check that?

Comment: The [lyrics](https://genius.com/Florence-the-machine-between-two-lungs-lyrics) don't mention an 'in' there.

Comment: And have you listened to the song? Is the phrase still grammatically correct though?

Comment: Could you kindly capitalize the word English in your question.

Comment: And Machine, as well please?

Comment: Florence Welch went to my old school.

Comment: Cool what school is that? How are the teachers there?

Comment: I hear an *in* in there. It's a little odd, but the grammar is correct. It's like: *It came from beyond the galaxy. It went from under the bed to inside the closet.*

Comment: Thank you tinfoil hat! You could also write an answer then.

Comment: @caiolucas - My old school is [here](https://www.alleyns.org.uk/)

Comment: Is that a private school because they want money?

Comment: It is a private school. In the 1960s they had free scholarships; I received one.

Comment: Why would you go to a private school when there are free public schools? Or does it have a special focus on a subject like a sport school?

Comment: My parents wanted me to have that education. The school was famous for its high standards.